# Display text above underline with padding

Tags: flutter, text, fonts, underline

Is there a way to achieve the following results in Flutter where the underline below text will be nicely hidden by the padding around letters that overflow it, such as 'g', 'q', 'y', etc?

Emulator (current):

[image: Emulator view]

Design (desired):

[image: Designed and desired view]

Font: **Spartan**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found to achieve that was to use text stroke and Stack to create the underline effect. Here is the code:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0),
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          bottom: 2,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Container(height: 1.0, color: const Color(0xFF2F3543)),
        ),
        Text(
          "Forgot password?",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            inherit: true,
            fontSize: 13.0,
            foreground: Paint()
              ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
              ..strokeWidth = 2
              ..color = Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "Forgot password?",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: const Color(0xFF2F3543),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            inherit: true,
            fontSize: 13.0,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

And the screenshot of the results

[image: Results]

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT**

The first one looks working but not looks good and the second one working fine but p word not that good.
When you dont want to add underline just write decoration:TextDecoration.none.

```
    Text.rich(
      TextSpan(
        text: 'For ',
        style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline, fontSize: 25),
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(text: 'g',style:TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none)),
          TextSpan( text: ' ',style:TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline, decorationThickness: 1)),
          TextSpan( text: ' p',style:TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none,)),
          TextSpan( text: 'assword?',style:TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline)),
          //you can add more text span here
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('For', style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline, fontSize: 25)),
        Text('g', style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none, fontSize: 25)),
        Text('ot', style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline, fontSize: 25)),
        Text(' ', style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline, fontSize: 25)),
        Text('p', style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none, fontSize: 25)),
        Text('assword', style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline, fontSize: 25)),
      ],
    )
```

[Working example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkWcQ.png)

Comment: whenever you reply, make sure to write some paragraphs that might clarify what you did. 

First of all, your example has errors since the parent `TextSpan` has the TextStyle decoration, the whole text will be decorated no matter what. Second, even though it looks like it handles the letter 'g' well, it doesn't handle the letter p as I mentioned. My question was whether there is an automated way to get padding around text that will overflow the bottom line.

Comment: Look at this answer may will help you out. I edited for you

Comment: thank you for editing your post. From your example, look at the letter 'p' - it has no underline below the rounded part whereas according to the design I need that. The solution I found (below) solves the problem.